# Link-time optimization with android-ndk r8e

Tags: android, android-ndk

I wanted to compile sources (SDL and similar things) using the new android ndk r8e. The changelog states "Enabled -flto in GCC 4.7, 4.6, Clang 3.2 and Clang 3.1". So I've added -flto to LOCAL_CFLAGS, LOCAL_CPPFLAGS and LOCAL_LDFLAGS. But the optimization and architecture flags arent in the linker call and therefore no optimization is done (aka slow binary). The linker also fails because it cannot find the functions from some .S files and some instructions aren't available in thumb mode. Everything worked fine without -flto.

So how to use the link-time optimization correctly and how to avoid this problems? And no, adding my own optimization/architecture flags to LOCAL_LDFLAGS is no answer because I want to use the NDK and not my own hacky build scripts.

The link-time optimization was also tested on an amd64 (non-android) using own build scripts and it worked fine (compiled, linked and 20% speed benefit). So please keep the answers to the NDK build system.

Comment: Here I am in 2019 and NDK/Clang still fails when I try to enable -flto=full :(